# Firebase Admin NodeJS SDK inside an AWS Lambda - admin.messaging().send(msg) timing out

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I am using the following code within an AWS Lambda function, the code works correctly, what happens is that looking at the server logs, the **send()** function usually reaches a timeout (greater than the 60 seconds duration of the Lambda).

When the timeout is reached, the lambda makes a retry.

By using this flow locally, the sending of notifications is successful and usually does not take more than 1 second.

Does anyone know what causes this problem?
Or how to solve it?

```
export async function sendEnquiryMessage(messagingEvent: MessagingEvent, fcmToken: string) {

    let content = {
        title: `new Message from ABC`,
        body: `'${messagingEvent.message?.text ?? ""}' `,
    };

    console.log("sending a message to FCM: ", fcmToken);
    const message = {
        notification: {
            body: content.body,
            title: content.title,
        },
        data: {
            clickaction: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
            id: '1',
            status: 'done',
            messagingEvent: JSON.stringify(messagingEvent),
        },
        apns: {
            payload: {
                aps: {
                    'mutable-content': 1,
                    'content-available': 1
                }
            }
        },
        token: fcmToken,
    };
    console.log("MESSAGE TO SEND: ", JSON.stringify(message));
    try {
       const messageId = await admin.messaging().send(message);
        console.log("MESSAGE SENT messageId ID was : ", messageId);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('Error FCM message:', e);
    }
    return true;
```

I am testing sending notifications via FCM implemented within an AWS Lambda function.

I hope the notification is sent correctly and a **timeout** does not occur.

Any help is welcome.

Thank you and happy new year.

Answer (score 0):

Once you catch error, console.error() requires string as an input.

Use .toString() method on error variable to convert it into string representation.

reference: https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#consoleerrordata-args

```js
export async function sendEnquiryMessage(messagingEvent: MessagingEvent, fcmToken: string) {

    let content = {
        title: `new Message from ABC`,
        body: `'${messagingEvent.message?.text ?? ""}' `,
    };

    console.log("sending a message to FCM: ", fcmToken);
    const message = {
        notification: {
            body: content.body,
            title: content.title,
        },
        data: {
            clickaction: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
            id: '1',
            status: 'done',
            messagingEvent: JSON.stringify(messagingEvent),
        },
        apns: {
            payload: {
                aps: {
                    'mutable-content': 1,
                    'content-available': 1
                }
            }
        },
        token: fcmToken,
    };
    console.log("MESSAGE TO SEND: ", JSON.stringify(message));
    try {
       const messageId = await admin.messaging().send(message);
        console.log("MESSAGE SENT messageId ID was : ", messageId);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('Error FCM message:', e.toString());
    }
    return true;
```

Comment: I will try it.

The thing is the function send() get a timeout, I dont know if this cause the error.

Thanks for your reply.